# Elasticsearch CPU spikes while Kibana refreshing

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am facing an issue with Elasticsearch, I see how it goes till 176% CPU usage in my server, so I was wondering whether this is a bug in this release or in the stack itself. It does not happen inmediatelly but after two hours I see these peaks on CPU usage that sometimes lead to an unresponsive server due to the load.

Is someone facing up with this issue as well?

My java version is

```
$~# java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

I have updated the configuration in Elasticsearch so that it consumes less CPU and memory. Now my elasticsearch.yml configuration is like this

```
indices.fieldata.cache.size: "30%"
indices.breaker.fielddata.limit: "80%"
indices.breaker.request.limit: "50%"
indices.breaker.total.limit: "90%"
bootstrap.mlockall: true
index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count: 1
indices.store.throttle.type: none
```

However, I still see the peaks of CPU usage from Elasticsearch, I have indentified their occurance when kibana refreshed the dashboard, them I can see peaks of >100% ( 107, 165...) .The weird thing is that memory usage, net I/O and block I/O seem to keep stable whereas the CPU spikes

Any suggestion or idea of a reason for this?

Thank you in advance,

regards!

And a log I was recording with top to search for the CPU peaks

> root@g:~# cat cpu-log.txt | grep colord
>
> 6.9   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.8   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.8   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.8   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.7   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.7   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.6   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.6   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.6   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.6   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.6   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.5   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.5   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.5   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 6.5   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> 7.3   389 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> **83.5  5864 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0**
>
> 57.5  5864 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
>
> **110  6949 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
>   -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0**
>
> **86.6  8100 colord   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
>   -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0**

Answer (score 0):

Debugging CPU usage is not such a simple task, a lot more information is required to figure out what is causing these spikes, things like the size of your cluster, the amount of data, number of shards and replicas, index mapping and also the properties of the dashboard you are visualizing.

In general, when querying and aggregating on Elasticsearch you **should** be seeing an increase in CPU usage, how much of an increase depends on the info I listed above.

As a starting point, I would suggest you follow this [production guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/deploy.html) for Elasticsearch since I see that you're running on some default settings, and also you might want to start by using the chrome network tools and reload your dashboard to see the network requests sent to Elasticsearch, run across all response to the `/_msearch` request and check the `took` value for each of the queries, this will give you a sense of the bulkier queries that ES might be struggling with.